# XML document element

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I want to write XML document which should show output as following, please help

```
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: How far did you get before you hit problems?

Comment: I am able to write about all types of XML documents, but I am unable to print data like this shape <111 222=333> 444 </111>

Comment: please help in it